# Access Html encoded field values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

How can I access "StudentID" value in JavaScript function(jQuery).

HTML:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Student.Models.vwStudent>>" %>

    <div class="divClass" id="divID">
      <table class="tableClass" id="tableID">
      <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr class="trClass" id="trID">
          <td class="tdClass">
            <%= Html.TextBox("StudentID") %>
          </td>
          <td class="tdClass">
            <%= Html.Encode(item.StudentName) %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% } %>
      </table>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $('#ShowStudentID').click(function () {        
      $(".tdClass").each(function () {
          alert($('.tdClass').children().val());
       // How do I access StudentID and StudentName here?
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the value for each td, which seems to be what you want to do, you can use the `this` keyword within the each loop. Something like this:

```
$('#ShowStudentID').click(function () { 
    $(".tdClass").each(function () { 
        alert($(this).text()); 
    }); 
 });
```

**Edit:**

To get the value of an input within the td element, you could do this within your each-loop instead:

```
alert($(this).find("input").val());
```

To make it a bit more specific, you could throw in the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) as well:

```
alert($(this).find("input[name='StudentID']").val());
```

**Edit 2:**

To get information from both `td` elements, you could do something like this instead:

```
$('#ShowStudentID').click(function () {
    $(".trClass").each(function () { 
          var tds = $(".tdClass", this);
          alert(tds.eq(0).find("input").val());
          alert(tds.eq(1).text());         
    });
});
```

You loop over the `tr` elements instead, select each `td` within it and treat them individually.

Here is a working example as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Hzfz2/

Comment: I get NULL values when I change the StudentID to a TextBox. I tried both this ways but it still returns Nulls:
<input type="text" name="StudentID"/>
<%= Html.TextBox("StudentID") %>

Comment: @user793468 Not sure I'm following you. If you still have the problem, please update your question with a little more context on this and I'll try to answer it.

Comment: But then I cant access the StudentName(Html.Encode(item.StudentName))

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access the encoded html in the `td with id=tdID` and do not need each

```
 $('#ShowStudentID').click(function () {                
       alert($('#tdID').text());                   
 });
```

Comment: Why the loop when you are selecting on an ID within it? You will always get the same value.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson What if there are multiple records(rows of data) and I want to loop through them?

Comment: @user793468 See my answer on how to handle multiple rows

Answer (score 1):

To access the `StudentID` value:

```
$('#ShowStudentID').click(function () {
    $(".tdClass").each(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

By the way, I wouldn't use the same IDs (`trID` and `tdID`) because the `id` attribute must be unique.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Student.Models.vwStudent>>" %>

    <div class="divClass" id="divID">
      <table class="tableClass" id="tableID">
      <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr class="trClass">
          <td class="tdClass">
            <%= Html.Encode(item.StudentID) %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <% } %>
      </table>
    </div>
```